# Reactive img src in Vue via API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm wondering, how should i solve this problem. I have api which is returning base64 image, and after entering the site, i want to load this img, any one have clues how or where should i put my function?

this is my api call which is in methods:

```
methods:{
    async getGraph(){
      const body = new FormData();
      body.append('hostname','hostname');
        axios({
          method:'post',
          url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/graph',
          data: body,
          headers:{"Content-Type":'multipart/form-data'}
        }).then(response=>{
                var graphBase64 = Object.values(response.data)[0]
                console.log(graphBase64)
                return graphBase64
        }).catch(function(response){
          console.log(response)
        })
    }
}
```

and i want to have it in this:

```
<img v-bind:src="getGraph()">
```

i was thinking maybe my api call should be in `beforeMounted` but after the site wouldn't load
Huge thanks for any clues/articles/ideas !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are close. you are binding to make it reactive but the wrong way.

`async` functions returns `Promise`: [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value).

You can instead create another variable instead and assign the value to that:

```
<template>
  <img :src="base64" />
</template>

<script>
data() {
  return {
    base64: "",
  }
},

mounted() {
  this.getBase64()
},

methods: {
  async getBase64() {
    // do async/promise stuff
    this.base64 = someValue
  }
}
</script>
```

Docs for the `mounted()` hook: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! it solved my poblem right away didn't know i needed to put it in data(). Thanks again!